# Получаю Null , когда в конструкторе передаю this

Tags: java, android

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
    static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

     public SplashScreen(){
         mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.acdc);
         mediaPlayer.start();
     }
}
```

на первой строке конструктора получаю Null , с сообщением о том, что невозможно создать экземпляр класса. Я так полагаю, что в момент отработки конструктора сам класс SplashScreen не полностью готов , еще не создался, чтобы передать себя .После чего он будет готов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Краткий ответ: в методе `onCreate`.

Обычно пустая и готовая ко всему активити выглядит примерно так:

```
public class ExampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_example);

        // Вот здесь можно начинать творить
    }
}
```

**UPD:** Только сейчас заметил. У Вас объявлен `static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;`, [не стоит так делать](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870656/should-singleton-pattern-be-used-for-android-mediaplayer), лучше объявите медиа плеер как обычное поле класса `private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;`. Если Вы хотите, чтобы Ваш медиа плеер был доступен дольше, чем живёт Ваша активити, воспользуйтесь [сервисом](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

Comment: да, я знаю что в onCreate . Но вопрос в том , почему в конструкторе нельзя передавать this, в данном случае под this кроется Context.  А насчет сервиса спасибо, мне нужно было чтобы плеер жил дольше чем  активити.  Если я хочу чтобы в один момент играла одна песня, а потом на другой активити начиналась вторая, а при возврате на прошлую активити Продолжалось воспроизведение первой песни , мне нужно создавать два экземпляра MediaPlayer?

Comment: Ну смотрите: если Вы загружаете ресурс, то контекст нужен для как раз для загрузки ресурса по его id. Если заглянуть в исходники класса `MediaPlayer`, то там прям сразу строчка `context.getResources().openRawResourceFd(resid)`, а если я правильно помню, `getResources()` вернёт `null` если вызвать его до того, как компонент (не важно активити или сервис) правильно инициализирован (то есть до `onCreate`). Почему именно так? Ну так работает платформа, нужно играть по её правилам. (продолжение в следующем комменте)

Comment: Если Вы хотите разные треки на разных активити, то да, нужно или несколько медиплееров или один, но переинициализировать его с новым источником. Первое будет работать быстрее, но потреблять больше ресурсов, и вряд ли подойдёт, если треков действительно много. Ещё есть такая штука как [`SoundPool`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html), никогда не использовал, но может вам подойти. Вообще, он, вроде, применяется для всяких коротких звуков (в играх, например), но по описанию он работает с набором аудио ресурсов, то есть то, что Вам надо.